# Backbone decodes my query strings

Tags: backbone.js, query-string, encodeuricomponent, decodeuricomponent

Backbone keeps decoding my query string params. For example when I do

```
var query_string = encodeURIComponent('New York')
Backbone.history.navigate('search?location='+query_string, {trigger: true})
```

I get an URL with path:

```
/#search?location=New York
```

instead of

```
/#search?location=New%20York
```

I'm not using pushState and I've read that in 1.0.0 version he decodes the fragment in the URL. So any suggestions how can I achieve this, or something similar maybe?

Comment: FYI your `encodeURIcomponent ` should have a capital `C`: `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: @Moogs it's a typo, sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Unicode characters in `location.pathname` are percent encoded so they're
>       decoded for comparison.

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1587

You might have to fork the library and remove or modify `decodeFragment` method.

Comment: Is it a problem if I simply have this types of URLs `/#search?location=New York&type=gym` ?

Comment: @VlatkoRistovski I don't see any problems with the way they implemented it